# wsgi: video in response does not play

Tags: python, html, wsgi

I have a very simple wsgi module:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return ["Here is the video: <video controls autoplay><source src='path-to-video/video.mp4' type='video/mp4' /></video>"]
```

I have the video on my machine and it is fine: if I open it in a browser it plays. From the wsgi, it does not. The video is there (from inspect elements), except that it's just a black box and does not play.

Screenshot attached:

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: When you say "open it in a brower", did you mean opening the html file?

Comment: @skyline75489 I mean two things: embedding that response string in a HTML file; opening the video file (through the path) in the browser. In both cases the file plays. I am using Chrome but the issue is on Firefox as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you path is incorrect.

When opening a html file, browser knows you are open a local file. The path in the html will also be treated as local path on the computer. I guess your path should be something like `/home/username/myvideo/1.mp4`. The broswer then finds that file and play it.

When using wsgi, you are sending request to the server (localhost, I assume). In that case, all the path will be used against that server root path (localhost://). The browser will attempt to get the file on `localhost://home/username/myvideo/1.mp4`, which will, of course, fail. That's why the video won't play.

Comment: I understand this, then which would be the right path to use in order to make the browser find the video?

Comment: You need to serve the video file. Most web frameworks like django and flask provides static file serving.

Comment: Yeah, I am not using django at the moment, I'd really need to see it by running the server on localhost.

Comment: I myself am not familiar with django. You may want to check out django's doc for static file hosting.